# How to extract audio from a web page on Android?

Tags: audio, nexus

I'm trying to extract the source audio from a podcast so I don't constantly have to go to the website and find the exact point I was at. It is directly from a web player which is embedded on a webpage that I visit.

As far as I'm aware it's not possible with any extensions because they are not compatible with the chrome browser on android (which I am using on my Nexus 5X).

Has anyone been successful in downloading an MP3 file from a webpage using their Android phone?

If any clarification is needed please let me know in the comments. Thanks!

Comment: Community bump prevention: this question was closed because the question seems to have been abandoned (OP hasn't visited the site more than 5 years and existing answers have no votes). If anyone can evaluate the existing answers, feel free to vote accordingly and reopen the question (or mod-flag the question requesting for reopening). For anyone else having the same issue, please post a new question and refer to this question as additional context.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Mp3fy](https://www.mp3fy.com).

Long hold the link to the podcast and copy the URL. Insert the compied URL to Mp3fy and let it work its magic.

If you could provide a link to the particular podcast so that we can check, that would be great too.